# Nearest Kronecker Product of a commutation matrix

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Given a commutation matrix ***$K$*** of the size ***$n²$ by $n²$***. How can I find matrix ***$A$*** and ***$B$*** both of the size
**$n$ by $n$** such that the equation below is (approximately) satisfied by finding its Nearest Kronecker Product.

***$K = A ⊗ B$.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $A = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}e_i e_j^T$, $B = \sum_{i,j} b_{ij}e_ie_j^T$.

First, we note that
$$
K = A \otimes B \iff\\
K = \sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}b_{pq} (e_ie_j^T) \otimes (e_pe_q^T) \iff\\
K = \sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}b_{pq} (e_i \otimes e_p)(e_j \otimes e_q)^T \iff\\
\operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}b_{pq} (e_j \otimes e_q \otimes e_i \otimes e_p) \iff\\
P\operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}b_{pq} (e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_q \otimes e_p) \iff\\
\operatorname{vec}^{-1}[P\operatorname{vec}(K)] = \sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}b_{pq} (e_j \otimes e_i)(e_q \otimes e_p)^T \iff\\
\operatorname{vec}^{-1}[P\operatorname{vec}(K)] = \operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(B)^T 
$$
For the permutation matrix $P$ satisfying
$$
P(u \otimes v \otimes x \otimes y) = u \otimes x \otimes v \otimes y.
$$

The [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K = K^{(n,n)}$ can be rewritten as
$$
K = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n (e_i \otimes e_j)(e_j \otimes e_i)^T, 
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_{i,j} e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_i \otimes e_j \implies\\
P \operatorname{vec}(K) = \sum_{i,j} e_j \otimes e_i \otimes e_i \otimes e_j
= \operatorname{vec}(K) \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}^{-1}(P\operatorname{vec}(K)) = K.
$$
All together, we are looking for $A,B$ that give us the best (approximate) solution to
$$
K = \operatorname{vec}(A) \operatorname{vec}(B)^T.
$$
Because $K$ is an orthogonal matrix, the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) tells us that every rank-$1$ matrix with spectral norm $1$ is an equally good approximation for $K$. In other words, for every $A,B$ we have
$$
\|K - A \otimes B\|_F^2 \geq n^2 - 1,
$$
and $\geq$ can be replaced with $=$ if and only if $\sum_{i,j,p,q} a_{ij}^2 b_{pq}^2 = 1.$